# Polar form of hermitian products

Tags: complex-numbers, inner-products

Let $\omega,a_1,\dots,a_n\in\Bbb R$ arbitrary real numbers. Consider the sum
$$
z = \langle a, t\rangle = a_1e^{-i\omega}+a_2e^{-i2\omega}+\cdots+a_ne^{-i n\omega}
$$
which is the hermitian product of $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in\Bbb R^n\subset\Bbb C^n$ and $t=(e^{i\omega},\dots,e^{in\omega})\in\Bbb C^n$

I was wondering whether there exists a known way to write it in polar form. Namely, I ask if there exists a formula to get $r=|z|$ and $\theta=\arg(z)$ in function of $a$ and $t$ such that
$$
\langle a, t\rangle = re^{i\theta}\;.
$$
Clearly
\begin{align*}
r&=|z|=\sqrt{[\Re(z)]^2+[\Im(z)]^2}\\
\theta&=\arg(z)=\arctan(\Im(z)/\Re(z))
\end{align*}
(this last one only if $\Re(z)>0$, see [Wikipedia for the all the cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis))), where
\begin{align*}
\Re(z)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\cos(\omega k)\\
\Im(z)&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\sin(\omega k)
\end{align*}
but the problem is that these expressions "unpack" and "split" both $a$ and $t$ with projections (e.g., $a_k=\pi_k(a)$ and $\cos(\omega k) = \pi_1(\pi_k(t))$).

What I am searching for is a similar expression but depending only on the vectors $a$ and $t$ "as a whole", without passing through projections.

Comment: This form of the scalar product is often used for the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ with $\mathbb{C} \in \mathbb{H}$:
$x = x_{0} + x_{1}i+x_{2}j+x_{3}k$ while complex numbers have only $x_{0}$ and $x_{1}$:
$$\langle x, y \rangle := x_{0} \cdot y_{0} + x_{1} \cdot y_{1} + x_{2} \cdot y_{2} + x_{3} \cdot y_{3}$$
$$\langle x, y \rangle := \Re(\overline{x}\cdot y) = \Re(x \cdot \overline{y}) = \frac{\overline{x}\cdot y + x \cdot \overline{y}}{2}$$